# Invalid module format with matching vermagic value

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, tegra

I have a problem with one of my kernel modules for Linux 4 tegra on the Jetson tk1. I'm trying to integrate a Camera driver into the kernel

I'm trying to insert a module into the kernel and I've compiled everything on the target machine. Here's the modinfo of the kernel module.

```
filename:       /home/ubuntu/mymodule.ko
license:        GPL v2
author:         John Doe
description:    SoC Camera driver
alias:          of:N*T*Cnvidia,mymodule*
alias:          i2c:mymodule
depends:
vermagic:       3.10.40-svn469 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8
parm:           test_pattern:int
```

The uname -r command outputs this :

```
3.10.40-svn469
```

I still get this output when I am running sudo insmod mymodule.ko

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mymodule.ko: Invalid module format
```

I've tried looking into the dmesg/syslog/kern log files but there's no information about why my module insertion is failing. I also looked around on other threads and it usually says to verify that the module was compiled using the correct headers. From my understanding, is the "vermagic" and the "uname -r" are similar I'm assuming that the versions are correct (I might be very wrong about that).

I'm running out of ideas and I'd like to know if I missed something.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build of the module?  What does uname -a say?

Comment: Have you tried `insmod --force mymodule.ko --verbose`?

Comment: What does uname -a output?

Comment: found any solution ??

Comment: I didn't find a solution for that problem but I used another kernel instead and everything I wanted to do works now. But unfortunately for that specific error I didn't find anything. I was using a third party version of L4T so my guess is that they added something to the kernel to prevent certain operations on their kernel.